# populating TableView from downloaded plist in Swift

Tags: swift, server, plist

I was hoping to resolve this without help but I seem to be going in circles even though I know it is not a difficult issue. So any help is much appreciated.

I have set up my App to populate a map and a TableView from data in a plist. All works well.  But now I am downloading the plist from a server which will, of course, place the file in a document directory. My question is, what is the Swift code for reading this from the directory rather than from the bundle?

This is some of the code for reading from the App bundle (note it all works, but I am not providing ALL the code here. Please don't point me to Apple Developer site - I've looked):

```
   if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testData", ofType: "plist"){
        if let arrayOfDictionaries = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path){
            for dict in arrayOfDictionaries {
                tableData.append(dict.objectForKey("title") as! String)
                stateData.append(dict.objectForKey("state") as! String)
                codeData.append(dict.objectForKey("code") as! String)
                infoData.append(dict.objectForKey("info") as! String)


            }
        }
```

This is the code for downloading the plist from the server:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
                downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
                didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL){

    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
    let fileManager = NSFileManager()
    let destinationURLForFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingString("/testData.plist"))

    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationURLForFile.path!){
        showFileWithPath(destinationURLForFile.path!)
    }
    else{
        do {
            try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(location, toURL: destinationURLForFile)
//             show file
            showFileWithPath(destinationURLForFile.path!)
        }catch{
            print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this. Odd how one can spend hours mulling over something. Then the next morning it seems obvious - and not without a little help from other SO postings :-) !!!

```
 let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let sourcePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("testData.plist")
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: sourcePath as String)
```